# C Error for dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have some issues with a main file.I have a matrix of structures (theoretically) and i want to modify all my "p" parameters in all the structures.
This is the main file:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int i, j;

struct PQ *queue;
queue = createQ(5);
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j = 20; j++);
    queue->mem[i][j].p = 1;
}

for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    puts("\n");
    for (j = 0; j <= 20; j++);
    printf("%d ",queue ->mem[i][j].p);
}


return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And this is another file which contains structures definiton and generate function:

```
typedef struct newLine{
    unsigned p;
} newLine;


struct PQ{
    struct newLine ** mem;
};

struct PQ *createQ(unsigned min){
    int i=0;
    struct PQ *newQ = malloc(sizeof(PQ));
    newQ->mem = malloc(min*sizeof(newLine *));

    for(i=0;i<=min;i++){
        newQ->mem[i]=calloc(20,sizeof(newLine));
    }

    return newQ;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with your compiler/linker output showing the error message you posted in the title of your question? It will help us significantly. Thanks.

Comment: main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:13:14: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
         queue->mem[i][j]->p = 1;
              ^
main.c:19:28: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
         printf("%d ",queue ->mem[i][j]->p);

Comment: `queue->mem[i][j]->p` --> `queue->mem[i][j].p` also `for(int i=0;i=min;i++){` : `i=min` is wrong.

Comment: I edited the initial post.Same behaviour."queue->mem[i][j].p = 1;" and "printf("%d ",queue ->mem[i][j].p);" from main file gives me dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error.

Answer (score 4):

You are seeing the error because struct is part of the type in C, so you have to use `struct newline` in struct PQ.
Another way is to use typedef to create type alias:

```
typedef struct newline {
    int p;
} newline;
```

The way to access struct's member is use . on struct, use -> on pointer to struct, so use `queue->mem[i][j].p` instead.

There are other problems.

You cannot dereference an uninitialized pointer, it yields undefined behavior:

```
PQ *newQ;
```

should be:

```
struct PQ *newQ = malloc(sizeof(struct PQ));
```

You should allocate with correct indirections:

```
newQ->mem = malloc(min * sizeof(newline*));
for(int I = 0;i < min; i++){
    newQ->mem[i] = calloc(20, sizeof(newLine));
}
```

Comment: I edited the initial post.Same behaviour."queue->mem[i][j].p = 1;" and "printf("%d ",queue ->mem[i][j].p);" from main file gives me dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error.

Comment: Are you include the other file in the main.c?

Comment: Yes.I hope I did it well.

Comment: You hope you did? did you actually do?